# How can I send a routine email using a list as input?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to write code in Python to help with sending an email that I send about twice a week, with the same format every time and just a few elements that differ between emails, so I wrote the following code to help with this:

```
def visitor():
    visitors = []
    number_of = int(input("How many visitors are you signing in? "))
    time = input("What time are they coming? ")
    comments = """
    Please type the name of the first visitor, and their nationality on the next line, the name of the second visitor
    and their nationality on the next line, until you wrote down all the names and nationalities.
    If you wanna stop the program and execute the code with the names & nationalities, just type quit
    """
    print(comments)
    name, i = "", 1
    while name != "quit":
        name = str(input("Ignore: "))
        visitors.append(name)
    visitors = visitors.pop(-1)
    email = f"""
                Hello,
                I have {number_of} visitors coming today at {time}.
                Name: {visitors[i]}
                Nationality: {visitors[i + 1]}
                """
    for i in range(len(visitors)):
        to_add = f"""
        Name: {visitors[i]}
        Nationality: {visitors[i + 1]}
        """
        email += to_add
    ending = "Awaiting your approval\nThank you"
    email += ending
    return email


visitor()
```

However, upon running this code, I run into a problem in line 25, saying "Index out of range" ( line 25 is Nationality: {visitors[i + 1]} ). This normally shouldn't happen since the list has more than one element. Can someone help with this?
P.S. I have another, way longer code written for this that works, but I wanted to try and improve it by making it less sloppy.

Comment: Please keep in mind that "line 25" is more helpful if you add a comment to that line so folks don't have to count and search.

Comment: A simple solution would be to create a list of dicts with name and nationality fields instead of a list of strings; indexing issues solved.

Answer (score 0):

The visitors list is acceeded at offset i+1, and i go up to len(visitors)-1 (upper limit specified for the loop through range()), so there is an access out of range when i = len(visitors) - 1

Comment: I created a variable called length, equal to len(visitors) / 2, and I used the range(length) function instead of range(len(visitors)) and the code is now working. However when I run visitors[I] I'm getting a letter instead of the element in the list. How can I fix this?